# asp.net webapi only works with GET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, umbraco

I've created a webapi with asp.net and made a few endpoints. When I run it on my production server it works but whenever I run the same thing on the live server every request I make becomes a GET.
For example, I have

```
 [System.Web.Http.ActionName("University")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpDelete]
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteUniversity(string token, int id)
{deletes something}
```

and

```
[System.Web.Http.ActionName("University")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<University> GetUniversity(string token, int id)
{shows some data}
```

If i make this request in Postman I'll get the GET result.

```
POST http://website.nl/umbraco/api/WebApi/University?token=token
{
"countrycode": "nl",
"name": "test"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. what does the request from postman look like?

Comment: I don't think you can create overloads of the same route based on the http verb. Try to call your actions differently.

Comment: POST doesn't match HttpDelete :-)